Restricting numeric fields to specific ranges using ArcGIS Pro Attribute Rules (Arcade)
Working in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 and trying to use Attribute Rules to restrict the values in a couple numeric fields. The ESRI documentation does not specify how this might be answered, despite my best effort: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/attribute-rule-script-expression.htm
I'm collecting geologic data where the Azimuth field (numeric) needs to be restricted to 0-359 and the Inclination field (numeric) to 0-90.
All I need is an Arcade expression to do so.

Have you read Attribute rule script expression examples - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation?

Yes--insufficient at a beginner level

Try creating an Attribute Constraint Rule for each field, and use the following Arcade expressions:
For Azimuth field
return ($feature.Azimuth >= 0 && $feature.Azimuth <= 359);

and for Inclination field
return ($feature. Inclination >= 0 && $feature.Inclination <= 90);

Set triggers to Insert and Update, and add an error message.

This will pop up an error message when you try to add a value outside the permitted range.

Note: My ArcGIS Pro required me to add a GlobalID field to my feature class for the rules to save.

Thanks very much!

@JAKeeley  Instead of adding a "thanks" comment, if this has answered your question please consider up-voting and marking as the answer.  See What should I do when someone answers my question?
